# Applying CSS Class on Individual Items vs Parent Children

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple menu using HTML and CSS. It looks like this:

```
.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  color:white;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}

<div class="menu">
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Although I do have a class for menu items called "menu-item" I was thinking what if I do this instead.

```
.menu div {
      display:table-cell;
      padding:12px;
}
```

When I apply class ".menu-item" to child divs they appear correctly horizontally spaced but when I use the ".menu div" approach they stack on each other. Why is that?

Comment: They don't do what you say when I test it. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k8khassb/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eqp1dvk3/

Comment: If you apply ".menu-item" class to individual div child items then they appear horizontally spaced out in a nice manner. Maybe it also depends on some other styles but those two are the main classes.

Comment: The code you mentioned produces the same result. Did you see both fiddles I posted? Are they not what you described?

Comment: Thanks! I am now 100% sure that some other parents styles are also applied to the div that somehow and for some reason changes the way it behaves.

Comment: That sounds possible. However you haven't posted that code.

Answer (score 0):

#### The approaches

Both approaches work. You might have mixed up something.

See `.menu div` approach:

```css
.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu div {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

See `.menu-item` approach:

```css
.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

---

#### The problem

Make sure you are implementing it correclty: for `.menu div` it doesn't need the `class="menu-item"`, while for the `.menu-item` it does need the `class="menu-item"` for its menu items.

It will only reproduce the way you described if you have used the `.menu-item` css approach but haven't placed the `class="menu-item"` to the menu items divs, hence the `.menu-item` styles won't be affected:

```css
.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Another possible problem

Maybe you're implementing the `.menu-item` correctly, but there are other css overwritting it, possibly due to a higher selector weight. Different browsers implement the weights differently, so you may notice that in this case the issue occurs just for a few browsers.

Example of competing styles:

```css
.menu div {
  display:block;
  padding:12px;
}

.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

To resolve that type of issue you will have to (a.) remove the overwritting style, or, if it's not possible: (b.) put a higher weight to your controlled style, for example, by using `.menu .menu-item` selector instead of just `.menu-item`:

```css
.menu div {
  display:block;
  padding:12px;
}

.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu .menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

If that still really doesn't help, maybe you'll need to add extra weight to overwrite a competing style, by, for example, using an auxiliar `id` to help:

```js
function addExtraWeight() {
  $("#extra-weight-removed").attr("id", "extra-weight");
}

function removeExtraWeight() {
  $("#extra-weight").attr("id", "extra-weight-removed");
}
```

```css
body div.menu.menu.menu div {
  display:block;
  padding:12px;
}

.menu {
  display:table;
  height:39px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color:rgba(213, 220, 228, 0.1);
}

.menu .menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}

#extra-weight .menu-item {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extra-weight" class="menu">
<div class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
<div class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
</div>

<button onclick="addExtraWeight()">Add extra weight</button>
<button onclick="removeExtraWeight()">Remove extra weight</button>
```

Comment: As I mentioned to the other person that answered saying the OP's code works, saying that their code works is not an answer, it's at best a comment.

Comment: @j08691 I didn't said the OP's *code* works. I said the OP's *approach* works. And pointed the differences between the two possible usages.

Comment: @j08691 I have also updated with a sample code of what the OP might have done wrong :P

Comment: The OP said himself that he believes the issue lies in other CSS he didn't post.

Comment: @j08691 I have updated again to cover that possible issue, including explanation and possible solutions.